# how to get decimal value from the import Ruler from react-native-animated-ruler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Currently, I am getting the integer value I want in the float value. how to achieve it in react-native-animated-ruler.

expo : [code link](https://snack.expo.dev/w8mMzyKbS?platform=android)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add `(value).toFixed(2)` to your code.

Comment: Not working. I tried. i think i need to edit the package

Answer (score 0):

in library at line 184

```
this.setState({
          value: Math.round(value / this.snapSegment) + minimum
        });
```

so you have to change this in package code.